# Partial Derivative Guidance.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was given this tricky problem in which I'm confuse on how to solve it and I would like some help:

Let $v(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable function. Let the function $u(s,t)$ be given by $u(s,t) = \sin(s)*v(s-2t,t^2)$. Compute $du/ds$ and $du/dt$ in terms of $v$ and it's partial derivatives.

My attempt (which is wrong):

Using chain rule:

- $du/ds=(du/dx)(dx/ds) + (du/dy)(dy/ds)$
- $du/dt=(du/dx)(dx/dt) + (du/dx)(dy/dt)$

So,

- $du/ds = \sin(s)*v(x,y)*s + \sin(s)*v(x,y)*0$
- $du/dt = 2t*\sin(s)*v(x,y) - 2*\sin(s)*v(x,y)$

Thanks,

Comment: When posting a question on this site, it is helpful to show us your work and specifically where you got stuck. This will help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing yourself with the $x$ and $y$ here. They aren't variables in $u(s,t)$, they're just variables in $v(x,y)$. In the definition of $u(s,t)$, you just input $s-2t$ for $x$ and $t^2$ for $y$, so this is really all in $s$ and $t$. Hence, you can just write $\partial u/\partial s=\sin(s)*\frac{\partial v(s-2t, t^2)}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial \sin(s)}{\partial s}v(s-2t,t^2)$ by the product rule. Then you can just evaluate $\frac{\partial v(s-2t,t^2)}{\partial s}$ by the chain rule. You can then do the same for $\partial v/\partial y$. Try that out by yourself.

Comment: I will try now.

Comment: Well,  by inputting $x = s - 2t$ and $y = t^2$ and calculating  $dv(s−2t,t2)/ds$ using the chain rule I get $dv/ds$ = dv/dx * dx/ds$ and $dv/dt = dv/dx * dx/dt + dv/dy * dy/dt$ I get that $dv/dx= 0$ and same for $dv/dy$ or am I doing something wrong again.

Comment: I still need some help. I'm not sure if that value's suppose to give 0.

Comment: You don't know what $v$ or its partial derivatives are, so you can't say that they're zero. The problem tells you to just leave the answer in terms of $v$ and its partial derivatives, so if you get something like $5v-3\partial v/\partial x$ (not the answer, just an example), you can leave it like that, because you can't say anything more.

Comment: Got it!! since we don't know the values that the function v might take, we just express the derivative of the function times the derivative of x with respect of s and so on! THANKS a lot!!

Comment: Haha . - Answered without checking your comment, thanks!